# innodb recovery from .ibd files

Tags: innodb, data-recovery

My website has crashed a few days ago.

The hosting company says some innodb database crashed.

They sent a MySql data folder. I tried to restore the database, but phpmyadmin is only showing MyISAM tables.

I checked the database with navicat. When I click innodb table, I got this error table 'xyz.wp_posts' doesn't exist.

is there anyway to fix this on windows?

Feel free to download db:

[www.degisimanaliz.com/xyzdb.tar.gz](http://www.degisimanaliz.com/xyzdb.tar.gz)

Very old backup:

[www.degisimanaliz.com/29_Ocak_Yedek_deganaliz.sql.gz](http://www.degisimanaliz.com/29_Ocak_Yedek_deganaliz.sql.gz)

Comment: Do you have the `ibdata1` file in there as well?  Are there any errors in the error logs when you start MySQL up?

Comment: no. i dont have a ibdata1                                     .120615 23:01:08 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table deganalizbozuk/wp_links from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
how you can resolve the problem.

Comment: you should have `ibdata1` file... otherwise very hard problem... try to search articles about recovering without `ibdata1`...

Comment: On `Stackoverflow` you might find this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100621/restoring-mysql-databases-when-reinstalling-wamp/34078329#34078329

Comment: Here is a great topic on StackExchange - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file

Answer (score 1):

There are settings in my.cnf that can be set to allow innodb to try to recover it's own tables[1]. These might be able to get you part of the way.If this does not help you, you have to get your hands dirty. I have used the percona recovery tools[2] a few times, with great success. Documented here[3]

And it might be a bad idea for you to share your databases with the internet. It can be very unforgiving.

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

[2] https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb

[3] http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/innodb-data-recovery-tool:start

Comment: i cant try percona. i dont have a linux.  if i can't save the data dont important security :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to recover from a crash I've had on one of my cpanel servers. If anyone else is reaching this let state that this [forum post](http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/mysql-innodb-crash-recovery-guide-11-23-11-24-mysql-will-not-start-101721.html) (cpanel) helped me. However, the script was old (2008) and was not working anymore. [I've fixed and posted back to here](http://madalin.eu/dumpdbsv1.txt), thinking someone might need it like I did. Simply download this instead of the one specified in that forum post.